# TSQL Combine query results if more than one

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, grouping

SQL Server 2016 -
I have a query which produces the result below but want to combine any multiple values for the block-subblock and if there is only a single value show that value.

```
    SELECT        
BLOCKS.[BLOCK-REF] AS [BLOCK-SUBB-REF]
, BLOCKS.[PLACE-REF]

, tenure.[ESTATE-CODE]

FROM            [SQLViewsPro2EOD].[dbo].[IH-LOCATION] AS BLOCKS INNER JOIN
                         [SQLViewsPro2EOD].[dbo].[IH-LOCATION] AS SUBB ON BLOCKS.[BLOCK-REF] = SUBB.[PLACE-REF] inner join
                         [SQLViewsPro2EOD].[dbo].[IH_ESTATE] tenure on tenure.[ESTATE-CODE] = blocks.[ESTATE-CODE]
                         AND SUBB.[LOCATION-TYPE] IN ('BLOCK', 'SUBBLOCK', 'CBLOCK', 'HOSTEL', 'SCHEME') and  SUBB.[BLOCK-REF] <> ''
                         and BLOCKS.[LOCATION-TYPE] in ('FLAT', 'BEDSIT', 'BUNG', 'DUPLEX', 'ENDTER', 'GFLAT', 'GFLATOG', 'HOSTEL', 'HOUSE', 'MAISON', 'SEMDET', 'ROOM')
WHERE  
(BLOCKS.[LOCATION-STS] <> 'D')
```

```
|BLOCK-SUBB-REF      | PLACE-REF    | ESTATE-CODE|
|103                 |1331          |PSLH   |
|103                 |1332          |GNSOC  |
|103                 |1333          |GNSOC  |
|103                 |1334          |GNSOC  |
|104                 |1335          |PSLH   |
```

Desired output

```
|BLOCK-SUBB-REF |Result
|103            | Mixed Results
|104            | PSLH
```

Thanks - Any help appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you could just use a `CASE` expression and check if the `MIN` and `MAX` values are the same:

```sql
SELECT BLOCKS.[BLOCK-REF] AS [BLOCK-SUBB-REF],
       CASE WHEN MIN(tenure.[ESTATE-CODE]) = MAX(tenure.[ESTATE-CODE]) THEN MAX(tenure.[ESTATE-CODE]) ELSE 'Mixed Results' END
FROM [SQLViewsPro2EOD].[dbo].[IH-LOCATION] BLOCKS
     INNER JOIN [SQLViewsPro2EOD].[dbo].[IH-LOCATION] SUBB ON BLOCKS.[BLOCK-REF] = SUBB.[PLACE-REF]
     INNER JOIN [SQLViewsPro2EOD].[dbo].[IH_ESTATE] tenure ON tenure.[ESTATE-CODE] = BLOCKS.[ESTATE-CODE]
                                                          AND SUBB.[LOCATION-TYPE] IN ('BLOCK', 'SUBBLOCK', 'CBLOCK', 'HOSTEL', 'SCHEME')
                                                          AND SUBB.[BLOCK-REF] <> ''
                                                          AND BLOCKS.[LOCATION-TYPE] IN ('FLAT', 'BEDSIT', 'BUNG', 'DUPLEX', 'ENDTER', 'GFLAT', 'GFLATOG', 'HOSTEL', 'HOUSE', 'MAISON', 'SEMDET', 'ROOM')
WHERE BLOCKS.[LOCATION-STS] <> 'D'
GROUP BY BLOCKS.[BLOCK-REF];
```

Comment: You're welcome, @user3306489 . If it answers the question, please do mark it as the solution, so that future readers know the answer was helpful. You might want to do this on some of your other [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3306489/user3306489?tab=questions) as well, as there's only a few where you have selected a solution.